# Setting up WordPress MU, wildcard dns and apache virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, wordpress

I manage a server that runs WordPress MU. The different blogs hosted on the server are accessible as subdomains, e.g. blog1.mydomain.tld, blog2.mydomain.tld, etc.

I also need to run a custom application (reports.mydomain.tld)  using the same server.

My virtual host configuration is as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost mydomain.tld:80
<VirtualHost mydomain.tld:80>
    ServerName mydomain.tld
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.tld
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.tld
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/mydomain.tld

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost reports.mydomain.tld>
    ServerName reports.mydomain.tld
    ServerAlias reports.mydomain.tld 
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.tld
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/reports.mydomain.tld/app/webroot/

</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access the subdomain reports.mydomain.tld,  WordPress [remainder of text missing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd advise against using hostnames in your `VirtualHost` and `NameVirtualHost` directives. Instead either use IP addresses or wildcards.

Additionally when NameVirtualHost'ing and a requested hostname could match either vhost, then the first vhost encoutered takes preference. In your case this would mean that the wildcard catches all.

You can also remove the extraneous `ServerAlias`.

Try instead:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName reports.mydomain.tld
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.tld
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/reports.mydomain.tld/app/webroot
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.tld
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.tld
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.tld
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/mydomain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com

  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

  DocumentRoot /path/to/my/app/
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule (.*)-cb\d+\.(.*)$ $1.$2 [L]

  <Directory "/path/to/my/app/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put

```
<VirtualHost reports.mydomain.tld>
    ServerName reports.mydomain.tld
    ServerAlias reports.mydomain.tld 
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.tld
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/reports.mydomain.tld/app/webroot/

</VirtualHost>
```

above

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.tld:80>
    ServerName mydomain.tld
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.tld
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.tld
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/mydomain.tld

</VirtualHost>
```

Should do the trick :)

Comment: The first argument of VirtualHost should be representative of HOW your site is accessed (i.e. the IP makes more sense). If you have not named this argument as a NameVirtualHost previously and it isn't sitting on it's own IP, then you're going to have unexpected results. Re-ordering doesn't fix the problem I'm afraid. Dan C's answer is a much better fix.

Comment: In the end reordering fixes it. And yea i wasn't careful on reading that he set it up as domains not ip's, but apache processes directives in the order it reads them, so reordering IS the fix in the end, not changing the domains to IP's.

Comment: In the end, i used a combination of both suggestions from you guys.
i.e.
1) Changed the NameVirtualHost  to be a wildcard
2) moved the reports.mydomain.tld virtualhost config above the *.mydomain.tld virtualhost config

Eventually, my final config looked like this


NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName reports.mydomain.tld
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.tld
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/reports.mydomain.tld/app/webroot

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.tld
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.tld
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/mydomain.tld

</VirtualHost>